# How to select all check boxes using jquery in spring form

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

This is the spring form, how to select all the checkboxes using jquery?

```
<form:form name="form" method="POST" commandName="da"> 
<table cellspacing="7">
    <tr>
        <td>Increment DA by:</td>
        <td><form:input path="da" id="da"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <form:checkboxes items="${empids}" path="empids" delimiter="<br/>" id="empids"/>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Save" ></td>    
    </tr>
</table>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give a common class to all checkboxes and then try this...

```
$('.commonClass').attr('checked',true);
```

Comment: Its works, thank you. You need to add class using cssClass attribute of the form checkboxes tag.

Comment: yeah...you nedd to do that. that's why i have written on top of my answer. any way it's great to here...that it works :)