# Button Text not changing

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

In my JSP form page what i am trying to do is change text button when form is filled. 
Here is html code

```
      <form:form id="requestForm"  method="get" name="myForm" modelAttribute="quickstartbean"  ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/quickstart/questions">

      <form:input type="text"  path="fName" value="${quickstartbean.fName}" id="fname" name="fname"   />

      <input type="submit" value="Skip and Continue" id="save_btn" style="background-color:  #98FB98;"></input> 
</form:form>
```

Here is my javascript

```
(function() {
                    $('form>input').keyup(function() {

                        var empty = false;
                        $('form>input').each(function() {
                            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                                empty = true;
                            }
                        });

                        if (empty) {
                            $('#save_btn').attr('value', 'Skip and Continue"  />');
                        } else {
                            $('#save_btn').attr('value','Save and Continue"  />');
                        }
                    });
                })()
```

But the value of button is not changing after fill the text field

Comment: that appears to be jQuery?

Comment: yeah its jquery

Comment: Your <input type="submit" ... > ends with </button>

Comment: I'm gonna guess that the value you are seeing not change is `Save and Continue` ?

Comment: Also, your form isn't closing, so technically there is no "form>input"

Comment: @SamAxe i want to change the button value from skip and continue to save and continue when the user fills the form

Comment: Your code seems to be working (in JSFIDDLE, I used form, not form:form and input, not form:input). Seems to be just fine.. https://jsfiddle.net/02mmxcw9/

Comment: @Goombah i am using <form:form> i my jsp. Is there a way it can be worked with <form:form>

Comment: did you check the javascript console in the browser or tried debugging?

Comment: @0riginal yes i did but its not working with spring tags <form:form>

Comment: @AxelH i am using spring only in project. Is there a way so that i can implement it using spring

Comment: @AxelH the next resulting page is also <form:form></form:form>

Comment: I would guess that your selector is not working `$('form>input')` since the tags are `form:form > form:input` but I can't test that.

Comment: It's old but look a this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120552/how-to-select-all-check-boxes-using-jquery-in-spring-form

Comment: did you add the taglib <%@taglib  uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form">? <form:form> should be rendered to a normal <form> tag in the browser

Comment: @AxelH it worked ..thanks

Comment: @Sarthak Did you tried Original solution ? It more useful (and more logical that Swing removed his own tag). The class is just a workaround, not a solution ;)

Comment: @AxelH yes i tried that also ...it works..thanks

Comment: @0riginal, you should add your answer to close this question ;)

Comment: @0riginal yes i already added the <%@taglib uri="springframework.org/tags/form"; prefix="form"> but it was then also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class in div tag

```
 <form:form id="requestForm"  method="get" name="myForm" modelAttribute="quickstartbean"  ACTION="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/quickstart/questions">

<div class="textbox">
          <form:input type="text"  path="fName" value="${quickstartbean.fName}" id="fname" name="fname"   />
</div>

          <input type="submit" value="Skip and Continue" id="save_btn" style="background-color:  #98FB98;"></input> 
    </form:form>
```

jquery code

```
 (function() {
                    $('.textbox').keyup(function() {

                        var empty = false;
                        $('textbox').each(function() {
                            if ($(this).val() == '') {
                                empty = true;
                            }
                        });

                        if (empty) {
                            $('#save_btn').attr('value', 'Skip and Continue');
                        } else {
                            $('#save_btn').attr('value','Save and Continue');
                        }
                    });
                })()
```

IT will work now